# Play HLS stream with GStreamer and souphttpsrc (fails after 10 secs)

Tags: gstreamer, http-live-streaming

The following pipeline fails after 10 secs.

gst-launch-1.0 -v  souphttpsrc location=https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8 ! hlsdemux ! decodebin  ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

For some reason i can't get it to play more of the stream.

This pipeline also fails after 10 secs.

gst-launch-1.0 -v uridecodebin uri=https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

I can get the stream to play with a playbin pipeline but unfortunately I can't use playin in my application as i need to link the pipeline to a app_sink.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the resolution changes after 10s from 1280x720 to 1920x1080.

You may try:

```
urisourcebin uri=https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8 ! decodebin ! queue ! videoconvert ! appsink
```

If your appsink expects a given resolution, you may use videoscale such as:

```
urisourcebin uri=https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8 ! decodebin ! queue ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink
```